# Mongo query search a string inside a map

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, spring-data-mongodb

I have managed to search a string type name inside the dto by using the following query,

```
@RestResource(path = "searchByName")
@Query("{'$and': [{'companyId': ?0}, {name : {$regex : ?1, $options: 'i'}}]}")
Page<Shop> findByName(String companyId, String name, Pageable pageable);
```

But now the name in the dto has changed to names which is a map,

old DTO,

```
class Shop {
    private String id;
    private String companyId
    private String name;
}
```

new DTO,

```
class Shop {
    private String id;
    private String companyId
    private Map<String, String> names;
}
```

Now the shop name has changed to names that contains names in different languages in a map.
ex:

```
{
    "EN": "Shop1",
    "SW": "affär"
}
```

So if client gives a text like 'sho' it should search inside the map values and should return the whole dto. How can I change the query to achive that?

Comment: I think the `names` should be a `List<Name>`, where `Name` POJO has properties `language`, and `name`. This will be stored in the collection's document as `names: [ { language: "EN", name: "Shop" }, { ....}, ...]`. Then you can easily query using the [Query an Array of Embedded Documents](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/tutorial/query-array-of-documents/index.html) features.

Comment: Thanks @prasad_, I'll try that approach. Btw can't we query values in maps like above?

Comment: You can. First convert the Map's data, i.e., the `names` sub-document as an array using the `$objectToArray`. Then iterate the array's values and match using a regular expression to search for the specific sub-string like "shop...".